# Insight Into System CPU Usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

We've noticed that **top** doesn't give much insight into sys CPU usage. It only appears to give CPU percentages for user.

Are there any tools out there that give more insight into System CPU usage?

Comment: It works fine for me. Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: Occasionally the sys cpu % will spike, but none of the processes seem to spike along with it.

Comment: What is the amount of iowait when this happens? My guess is quite high.

Comment: Doesn't seem to spike with the sys, stays around 0.35%

Answer (score 1):

The `sysstat` utilities are very helpful for getting more details: http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/

But it would be easier to help you if you describe more exactly what details about your CPU usage you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to check out those in perticular:

To see detailed utilization of each CPU (core) you could use 
atop http://linux.die.net/man/1/atop and learn it's CPU section in perticular.
it is a good practice to fixate (f) output to see all resources, even inactive:

```
# atop -f 2
```

If you would like to inspect some process (and their child processes), you could use
strace http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace

```
# strace -cfrv -p [some PID]
```

and inspect CPU time spent running in the kernel.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.